# httphandler: Could not load type 'Upload'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm still trying to follow this sample:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FlashUpload.aspx

Under Visual Studio it's working fine but, when I try to publish on IIS it doesn't works. This is the situation: under my Website I created a Upload.vb class under App_Code folder that implements IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState.

On web.xml I wrote this rows:

```
<remove verb="POST,GET" path="Upload.axd"/>
<add verb="POST,GET" path="Upload.axd" type="Upload"/>
```

On Page.aspx I added this code:

```
<FlashUpload:FlashUpload ID="flashUpload" runat="server" 
    UploadPage="Upload.axd"
    FileTypeDescription="Images" FileTypes="*.doc; *.xls; *.pdf; *.docx; *.xlsx" 
    UploadFileSizeLimit="0" TotalUploadSizeLimit="0" />
```

I followed the sample and my class has not namespace. I read on internet that this error happens when IIS is not able to find the class.

Could you help me?

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify like this type="Upload, App_Code".

Comment: I tried and this is the message: "Could not load file or assembly 'App_Code' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"